# Oracle select query with Json field

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I want to fetch data from below table.

Table Name: `Insight`

```
Id  |  Name      |  JSON_DATA
----+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  Sitansu.  |  {"country_codes": ["IND"],  "regions": ["ASIA"]}
2   |  Sitansu.  |  {"country_codes": ["IND","USA"],  "regions": ["ASIA","NA"]}
```

How to fetch data from this Insight table  based on region like “NA” . But I don’t want to fetch data by using like query.

Example: `country_codes == IND`  then it should show  2 records as per above table example. Also I want to fetch data with multiple country code.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @ErgiNushi Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Oracle 11g does not have a function you can use for parsing JSON from query. You can use `APEX_JSON` but it will require PL/SQL in order to loop JSON object.

Comment: @ErgiNushi Can you please share any example related to APEX_JSON

Comment: Documentation is a good way to start: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm#AEAPI29635

Comment: Without using like it is impossible to achieve. The way your results are stored in the table you would never be able to use an = operator. The only other way I can think of is format the JSON first before inserting the data into the table. Alternatively if you want to use REGEXP, is another possibility: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm